# No binary operator was found where it is defined C2679 and C2678 error code

Tags: c++

I've got a little problem with two binary operators exacly "<<" and "==" But firstly I have to explain my plan. So I planned to create template class frequencycounter with my own map. Map should take variables and counting number of frequency of those variables. In Source I wanted to add Template  types of data like  from vector of colors. My color is struct of three variables as Red Green Blue. Earlier I had class ppm which was loading an image in constructor. Image class is base class for ppm. 
Here is the code.

Headers which are included :image.h,ppm.h,color.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "color.h"
#include "freqcounter.h"
#include "ppm.h"

int main()
{

    freqcounter<color> color_count;
//  
    Image *ob;
    ob = new ppm("Lenna.ppm");

    std::vector<color> test = ob->pixel;

    for (auto i = test.begin(); i != test.end(); i++)
    {
        color_count.addData(*i);
    }

    color_count.create();



    system("Pause");
}
```

## frequencycounter.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <set>

#include "Image.h"
#include "ppm.h"
#include "color.h"

template <typename T>
class freqcounter
{
public:
    freqcounter();
    ~freqcounter();

    unsigned int counter;
    std::vector<T> vec;

    std::vector<color> pixels;
    void addData(T num);
    void create();

};

template<typename T>
 freqcounter<T>::freqcounter()
{

}

template<typename T>
freqcounter<T>::~freqcounter()
{

}
template<typename T>
 void freqcounter<T>::addData(T num)
{
    vec.push_back(num);
}

template<typename T>
void freqcounter<T>::create()
{
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "enter name of file" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> name;
    std::ofstream ofile;
    ofile.open(name, std::ofstream::out);
    std::set<T>vec_of_uniq(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    for (const auto& elem : vec_of_uniq)
    {
        licznik = std::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), elem);
        std::cout<< elem << " " << counter << "\n";
    }

}
```

## color.h:

```
#ifndef COLOR_H
#define COLOR_H
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

struct color {

 bool operator<(const color & right) const
    {
        return std::tie(R, G, B) < std::tie(right.R, right.G, right.B);
    }
    unsigned int R;     
    unsigned int G; 
    unsigned int B; 

};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ob, const color& ob1)
{
    ob << ob1.R << ob1.G << ob1.B;
    return ob;
}
inline bool operator == (const color& left, const color& right)
{
    return std::tie(left.R, left.G, left.B) == std::tie(right.R, right.G, right.B);
}
```

## ppm.h:

```
#ifndef PPM_H
#define PPM_H
#include "image.h"

class ppm : public image
public:
    ppm();                      
    ppm(std::string name );         
    ~ppm();                     
};
#endif
```

## ppm.cpp:

```
#include "ppm.h"



ppm::ppm():image()
{

}

ppm::ppm(ppm & copy) : image(copy)
{
}

ppm::~ppm()
{
}

ppm::ppm(std::string filename)
{
//  std::string hash;

    std::ifstream file;                             
    file.open(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::out);

    if (plik.good())
    {
            file >> head;
            file >> height;
            file >> width;
            file >> balance;
            for (int i = 0; i < (width*height); i++)
            {
                file >> structs.R;
                file >> structs.G;
                file >> structs.B;
                pixel.push_back(struts);                
            }

            plik.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "no file " << std::endl;

    }

}
```

image.h//

```
#ifndef IMAGE_H
#define IMAGE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <exception>
#include "color.h"


class image
{
public:


    image();                        
    image(const image&copy);        
    image& operator=(const image &M1);  
    virtual ~image();                   

     color getColor( int i, int j);


    std::vector <color> pixel;                              

protected:
    color structs;                  
    int height, width, balance;         
    std::string head;                   


};
#endif
```

My method. for counting types and their frequency is defined in create function as

```
std::set<T>vec_of_uniq(vec.begin(), vec.end()); 
for (const auto& elem : vec_of_uniq)
{
    counter = std::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), elem);  // err code 2679 if 
// comment next line   
        ofile<< elem << " " << counter << "\n"; // err code 2678
    }

}
```

And "==" operator and "<<" for saving to file opearator is not visible. ( Exacly C2679 error code in Visual Studio )  but I've already defined this two operators in color.h
How to solve this problem ? 
My solution works for simple types as strings,chars, and ints but it has problem with lambda expresion of count:: method. 
By the way. If those method is not so great, what is yours suggetion for solve this problem ? Main problem is creating own template map which counts the number of occurrences and saving to the file ( as the best in source .cpp but with this method I haven't idea how to move it. Thanks for all responses.

Comment: _"C2679 error code"_ Where? Post the exact quote of the error including the line/column information that it gives you, and annotate that line in your source code. You should also try to reduce the code down to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - which will not only make it easier for people to read - but might even help you find the cause along the way.

Comment: and regarding the _"By the way"_, you should ask only one question at a time. Keep this one about the error in the code, after adding the missing info - then if you get it working but want reviews about how it might be improved, that's another question and better placed on Code Review.

Comment: color.h is probably not included in a compilation unit (source file) in which it is needed.

Comment: color.h is included as project file and in source file

Comment: Post all the code needed to replicate the problem, as separate code blocks for each complete file. Just scattering which fragments of each file you think are relevant is not helpful.

Comment: Already I've done it. I'm sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: The ppm class declration you posted lacks a `{` in ppm.h and in the constructor you also declare `std::ifstream file;` but then use `plik.open(...);`. Is it a typo? Why don't you simply write `std::ifstream file(filename);`?

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you are having a problem with `operator<` for `color` struct. If you want to create `set<T>` with your type, `operator<` for your type should be defined as const member.

```
bool color::operator<(const color & right)  const // <---
{
    return std::tie(R, G, B) < std::tie(right.R, right.G, right.B);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything. Still In line  where std::count is using I've got C2678 error code and next line when I'm trying to cout elem and counter is error code C2679

Comment: @Return.h You should edit your post and add info - which headers are included in particulars your files.

Answer (score 0):

Could it really be as simple as your #include guards are wrong in image.hpp?

You labeled it image.cpp, but it's clearly a header.  And you are testing the color_H value inside the image header, which seems wrong.

However, in the code you posted, it's all capital letters in the actual color.h header, so maybe this is a red-herring.  But if you edited anything you posted, which, IMHO, is way too much, then it's hard to tell.

You wrote this:

```
image.cpp:

#ifndef color_H
#define color_H
...
class image
{
public:
```

Assuming you actually spell them the same (which is a guess), then the COLOR_H is already defined when you include color.h and you won't see the contents of the header.

Comment: It is caused by my tiredness beacuse I am writing in my national language, and I have to translate all names to english, and just not copied all the headers. You can accept that I've included all headers correctly. It is not main problem. It will be edited.